# Joomla redirect for private page access

Tags: joomla2.5

I have latest install of joomla 2.5 with rsmembership registration. i already done configuration in rsmembership that it redirect from core registration link to rsmembership registration page. but its not over yet.

I have many articles on home page modules or somewhere in menu which needs user to login. so what i need is if user click on read more of private article from homepage module or they click on private page menu item they redirect to registration page, instead of this they are redirected to homepage right now.

Anyone know how can i change this redirection while user click on link of private page and they redirected to registration page.

Comment: Rsmembership is a commercial extension, consider contacting the developer.

Comment: This question isn't really about the extension.

Comment: I don’t know about Joomla in detail, but I think access rights in most CMS are applied on an “all or nothing” level regarding the articles – so I don’t think something like “allow a guest to view the excerpt/teaser of an article, but not the whole article” is implemented already; you’ll have to work on that yourself. (Maybe by overwriting access control on those pages that only fetch article teasers or something.)

Comment: I need some expert of joomla developer to look into it. as we know joomla hide everything which having access level registerd. so solutions are given by joomla doc is using alias menu. same i have articles access public, so it shows in module but same time they are in category which is having access registered. so when user tries to see full article from link in module, he can't see, he needs to login or register. at this stage i need user redirect to register page or login page instead of homepage.